# Windows Terminal opening file with different program

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, notepad

I want to open an index.html program from my terminal. I can do this in notepad by simply typing:

> start notepad index.html

or even just:

> notepad index.html

My class wants me to use Visual Studio Code to write my programs, so my question is how do I open the index.html file with Visual Studio Code? I have tried doing the same format as above, but with quotes around "Visual Studio Code" since it has spaces, and it hasn't worked. I feel like this should be an easy fix, so please let me know, thanks.

Comment: **Bold** is to be used for **emphasis**, not for your entire post.. Please don't use bold everywhere. Thanks. (And the name of *Visual Studio Code*  from the command line is `vscode`, which does not have spaces.)

Comment: You are writing programs using an IDE (Visual Studio Code) but you want to run `notepad`.  Why?  Why not just load the html file directly into Visual Studio?

Comment: @cdarke That is exactly what I was asking how to do. But I figured it out. For me, I have to type:

Code index.html

Comment: So how was that related to `bash`?